# Jersey JAX-RS REST "getter" method always called

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, bean-validation

I am running a web application in Glasshfish 5 that provides a REST endpoint using Jersey JAX-RS. It also uses bean validation.
The problem I am having is that any method starting with "get" is always called when it returns something that has the @Valid annotation.

Example:

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloResource {

  @GET
  public @Valid HelloMessage getSomething() {
    HelloMessage helloMessage = new HelloMessage();
    helloMessage.setMessage("Hello World!");
    return helloMessage;
  }

  @POST
  public @Valid HelloMessage updateMessage(@Valid HelloMessage message) {
    return message;
  }
}
```

If I do a POST to /hello, you will see the getSomething method being called, before updateMessage is called.
If I remove the @Valid annotation on the return type of the getSomething method, then getSomething is not called.

Is this according to specifications? Should you basically never name a method starting with "get" in a REST class?

In the past I have reported an issue for this on github, but never received a reply.

https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/3743

Other classes:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class HelloApplication extends Application {

  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    return Collections.singleton(HelloResource.class);
  }
}

public class HelloMessage {

  @Size(max = 100)
  private String message;

  public String getMessage() {
    return message;
  }

  public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
  }
}
```

Minimal project to be found at 
https://github.com/robertatgh/stackoverflow-50658396/tree/develop

Comment: Can you put this into a minimal reproducible GitHub repo? Minimal also meaning no `@ApplicaitonScope` CDI injection as it is not part of the problem.

Comment: I have removed the @ApplicationScoped and put a minimal project at https://github.com/robertatgh/stackoverflow-50658396/tree/develop

Comment: Thanks for the project. I made a [PR](https://github.com/robertatgh/stackoverflow-50658396/pull/1) that makes the project a complete and runnable example. I was able to reproduce the problem. Not sure why it is happing. Weird stuff.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha, when I run it says `[INFO] Started o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@19569ebd{/test,file:///Users/tarunlalwani/Documents/Projects/SO/stackoverflow-50658396/target/webapp-tmp/,AVAILABLE}{file:///Users/tarunlalwani/Documents/Projects/SO/stackoverflow-50658396/target/webapp-tmp/}
[INFO] Started ServerConnector@2bbb44da{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}` but the directory is empty and the endpoint gives 404?

Comment: @TarunLalwani You can ignore that. It should say "Started Jetty Server". The endpoint is `http://localhost:8080/api/hello`

Answer (score 3):

So this turned out to be a funny kind of an issue because of the naming convention. Debugging through the jersey source code you will see that it goes through

**org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.DefaultConfiguredValidator.onValidate(ValidationInterceptorContext) line: 166**

```
public void onValidate(final ValidationInterceptorContext ctx) {

    final Object resource = ctx.getResource();
    final Invocable resourceMethod = ctx.getInvocable();
    final Object[] args = ctx.getArgs();

    final Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> constraintViolations = new HashSet<>();
    final BeanDescriptor beanDescriptor = getConstraintsForClass(resource.getClass());

    // Resource validation.
    if (beanDescriptor.isBeanConstrained()) {
        constraintViolations.addAll(validate(resource));
    }

    if (resourceMethod != null
            && configuration.getBootstrapConfiguration().isExecutableValidationEnabled()) {
        final Method handlingMethod = resourceMethod.getHandlingMethod();
```

The interesting part is around

```
// Resource validation.
if (beanDescriptor.isBeanConstrained()) {
    constraintViolations.addAll(validate(resource));
}
```

The definition of the same is

```
@Override
public final boolean isBeanConstrained() {
    return hasConstraints() || !constrainedProperties.isEmpty();
}
```

Now if you look at the value of `constrainedProperties` it shows below

[image: getSomething is a property]

So it thinks that `getSomething` means a property `something` which then inserts a validation on the property itself.

So now if we rename the method like below

```
  @GET
  public @Valid HelloMessage doGetSomething() {
    System.out.println("* * * *---==** getSomething() called **==---* * * *");
    HelloMessage helloMessage = new HelloMessage();
    helloMessage.setMessage("H");
    return helloMessage;
  }

  @POST
  public  @Valid HelloMessage updateMessage(@Valid HelloMessage message) {
      message.setMessage("H");
    System.out.println("* * * *---==** updateMessage() called **==---* * * *");

    return message;
  }
```

And run it again from command line

[image: getSomething is not Called]

And of course if I correct the return value with valid data

[image: getSomething not called]

Comment: Nice. `// Resource validation.` I didn't know that the resource classes are validated. Everything makes sense with the world again :-). Hey is that really Eclipse? Looks awesome. How do you get it to look like that (dark theme)?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha, yes it is eclipse with [Darkest Theme](https://www.genuitec.com/tech/darkest-dark/)

Comment: @TarunLalwani I sort of expected this to be the case. However can we say that this is a bug in Jersey? Because to me it should not validate the resource "properties". Furthermore, it is quite natural to name methods in a resource endpoint starting with "get" for HTTP GET methods.

Comment: @Robert, I think that is upto to Jersey team to decide. They might say it is a feature and to you it is a bug. So I would just open an issue with them and ask for a flag to control this behaviour.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I opened an issue on 24 December 2017, but never got a reply. Is there another way to contact the team?

Comment: Hey @Robert you can check out [my two cents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50752118/2587435) on the matter. I personally don't think that trying to use the same validation process for the return value is appropriate. I recommend a different approach.

Comment: @Robert, also I haven't seen anyone using `@Valid` annotation on return values. It is also like a masking a issue with in your code. When you get input from user, you are not sure if it's valid or not. But when you do things yourself you should know if the objects is valid or not. Using `@Valid` for return values is like you don't care if your code fails to return the correct data, it should be caught and handled in your function as such

Comment: @TarunLalwani That is exactly what Valid annotation will do . Together with an ExceptionMapper implementation, you can create the response you like based on the ConstraintViolationException, and set the HTTP status to 400 for violations of incoming data, and 500 for returned data.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding my two cents on top of [Tarun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50715196/2587435).

When I saw that Jersey validates the resource classes, I was trying to think of the use case as to why It would be validated. And the reason I can come up with is the case where we are injecting `@PathParam`s and other `@XxxParam`s as fields into the resource

```
@Path("/person/{email}")
public class PersonResource {

    @Email // email constraint validator
    @PathParam("email")
    private String email;
}
```

Instead of injecting the `@PathParam` into the resource method parameter as you would normally see, we are injecting it as a field. And when the resource gets validated, the `email` field will go through the email constraint validator.

As far as properties are concerned, they can be fields or JavaBean style methods (which are also referred to as "properties"), which are getter and setter method that begin with `get` and `set`, respectively. So our naming of methods with `get` and `set` adds them to the list of properties.

Now I don't know if the developers thought of this when they design the code, but if they did and they decided it wasn't a problem, I would guess their argument is this: the bean validation with Jersey is meant to validate *incoming* data; this can be data coming in from the client as the entity body or as different parameters, such as in the path, header, or query string. The common factor is that they are all *incoming* from the client. Therefore, if there is some constraint violated, it would be a *client error*, hence the 400 Bad Request response status, which means a *client error*.

That being said, when we have return values in our resource methods, those are *not* client gathered data; those are values produced by the server side processing. So if there is some constraint violated on those objects, they *shouldn't* be processed with the same semantics as the client *incoming* objects. Yeah you may want those objects validated, but IMO this should be validated in a different process and should not result in the same 400 as would be with a client side error. It should result in maybe a 500 Internal Server Error. Its definitely not the client's fault that there is a problem with the return value. We as developers should make these checks.

Now, if you *do* want to validate the return value yourself, you can just use the validation APIs to manually do the validation. And to keep it DRY and done transparently, you can use the [AOP capabilities](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/aop-example.html) of HK2 (Jersey DI) to intercept the method call. I put together a PoC in this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-validate-return).

Comment: That might indeed be the reasoning behind it. I'll take a look at the PoC.